# Supressing 'Permission Denied' warning in du command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to list the size of all sub-folders in a directory. when I try 
`du -h --max-depth=1` the output is cluttered with 'Permission denied' statements as such

> du: cannot read directory `./folder_name': Permission denied

How can I suppress these warnings?

I tried a workaround by piping the the output to grep as follows

`du -h --max-depth=1 | grep -v 'du:'`

but that does not seem to be working either!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1 2>/dev/null
```

This redirects *stderr* (file handle 2) to `/dev/null`, ignoring any error messages.

Comment: Is there a reason why `grep -v` doesn't work?

Comment: The reason your `grep -v 'du:'` doesn't work is because the error messages are on the stderr stream. In a pipe such as the one shown it's the stdout stream which is redirected from one command to the next, and thus the `grep` command never sees the error messages.

Comment: @sandy: Recommended reading: [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

Comment: Note that you could *make* the grep command work by redirecting `du`'s stderr stream to stdout. Try `du -h --max-depth=1 2>&1 | grep -v 'du:'`. Best of luck.